Write shell command to find long if statements within a directory of php files
I have a nested directory of files in php, some of them may have if and else conditions within them
if (condition) {
  // ~100 lines of code
}

I want to quickly find those [files/start of if or else condition] within files that have long bodies within if or else conditions. Say > 100 lines within the flower brackets
Eg:
File1:
    if (condition) {
      // >100 lines of code
    } else {
     // 50 lines of code
    }
    ...
    if (condition) {
      // 10 lines of code
    }
File2:
   if (condition) {
     // 2 lines
   }

should return the line number of the first if condition from File1 because it has 100+ lines within its opening and closing brackets. There could be nested if conditions as well

What have you tried? How did it fail?

What is an if-loop?

Don't tell me that you are trying to write a PHP parser in bash and awk???

There could be nested if conditions as well : What is the expected outcome, if a text looking like an if condition happens to be part of a multi-line comment or a multiline string?

depending on the variability of the code, it might not be achievable with line oriented processing tool like awk or sed. It may require to use a proper parser. Maybe something like semgrep.

In all questions, please provide a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output covering all of your use-cases (e.g. nested ifs) that we can copy-paste to test a potential solution against. Obviously then don't make your target range 100 lines, make it 5 or 10 or something else reasonable to post in a question.

I suspect what you're actually looking for is some measure of cyclomatic complexity, which you could accomplish pretty easily with PHPCS. I'm not sure what use an actual physical line count is, but if you insist on that, PHPCS gives you the parsing framework to do so, you could write a fairly simple sniff to detect violations of your limit.

You cannot do this job robustly without writing a parser for PHP but if you're happy with a simple, best-effort tool that'll work for the format you show where if only appears as the first "word" on a line if it's the start of an if-condition and the matching } is always indented the same way as the if, an else is always on the same line as the ending }, etc. then just using mandatory POSIX tools you could do the following:
find . -name '*.php' -exec \
    awk -v numLines=100 '
        /^[[:space:]]*if[[:space:]]*\(.*\{/ {
            begNr[++depth] = FNR
            sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"")
            endRe[depth] = "^" $0 "}"
        }
        depth && match($0,endRe[depth]) {
            if ( (FNR - begNr[depth]) >= (numLines + 2) ) {
                print FILENAME, "match started at line", begNr[depth]
            }
            if ( substr($0,RLENGTH+1) ~ "[[:space:]]*else[[:space:]]*\{" ) {
                begNr[depth] = FNR
            }
            else {
                depth--
            }
        }
    ' {} +

In the case of nested ifs, if one contains >= 100 lines then any it is nested within also contain >= 100 lines and so will also be reported as such.
The above is, obviously, untested since you didn't provide sample input and expected output we could test with.
